# I got this error but don't know how to fix it, www.example.com/undefined?1460018627809

Tags: javascript

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.example.com/undefined?1460018627809

Comment: seams like the url is wrong. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

Comment: You can check this easily with the google chrome developer tools!

Comment: your href (possibly a javascript redirect?) seems to be pointing to a page that does not exists;

Comment: I try to find that but i don't see it.

Comment: Are you creating the URL dynamically with Javascript? It looks like you have an undefined variable where the filename is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

`404` error means that requested page does not exists. So make sure that `example.com/undefined` links to existing place.

Comment: I tried to find this(undefined?1460018627809) in my project folder but i couldn't see it.

Comment: @AdventureLoopAsia `undefined` must be either .htaccess directive to some actual file (because it does not have extension) OR `undefined` is caused by your script that does not receive any value. `?1460018627809` is just parameter that will never be part of file name